# How to use Index in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I am new to SQL. If i create an index on a column, I know it is going to make the search faster. But how do I use the index later? For example, CREATE INDEX ID_INDEX ON Students(ID); Is there a SQL command that shows how I use this index? If I also do SELECT * FROM Students WHERE ID = 3, is there a big difference?

Comment: You don't use it directly, the database uses it automatically to optimize queries.

Comment: The `EXPLAIN` statement will tell you which indexes a query is using.

Comment: Bigger differences in performance gains come once the data gets bigger. Indexes are used for retrievals (like what you've given in an example), when you `GROUP BY`, `JOIN ..`, and `ORDER BY`. Correct indexing is a good practice to get into. For a primary unique identifier a `PRIMARY KEY` (there can be only one) might be more appropriate which is also a special kind of index.

Comment: You have to weigh the "amount of insert" vs "amount of querying" you will do on the table. Indexing will negatively impact the INSERT performance and positively impact the general querying performance. Look into your needs, before you go through with the indexing

Comment: any column called `id` is likely to be a primary key, in which case it's already indexed

Comment: Thank you all. :)

Answer (score 1):

Deciding what indexes to use, and whether they should be on single columns or multiple columns, is a task that takes some learning.  See this: https://use-the-index-luke.com .

But here's the really REALLY cool thing about indexes:

The MySQL server software *automatically* figures out how to apply them to satisfy SQL queries.  So, we can add or remove indexes during the lifetime of a database, with absolutely no change required to the queries. New indexes can sometimes dramatically speed up queries, sometimes by taking O(n**2) or O(n) operations and converting them to O(log n) in complexity.

This is important, seeing as how the lifetime of a database for a successful application is measured in decades, not years.  As a database grows with use, new indexes keep it humming along.

Comment: Thank you very much